# What's with Raven telling Cinder to kill Qrow?

Tags: rwby

What is with Raven telling Cinder to kill Qrow then attacking him herself only to go and kill Cinder but Qrow is still alive was this some kind of trick? Did Qrow and Raven plan to kill Cinder the whole time and secretly in on a plan together? Or was Raven serious but changed her mind and not really want Qrow dead?

Answer (score 3):

The way I see it, Raven did an analysis and realised that she might be able to take Cinder if it came down to it. Not a plan she'd usually go with, but she had her back to the wall here. To maximise the odds of success she doesn't want to fight her entire party alongside Cinder. So she tells them to go after Qrow as well, so at least some of Cinder's party would be distracted or out of action as a result of dealing with Qrow's group. 
And this is exactly what ended up happening, with Cinder's group bogged down fighting Qrow's and only Cinder going down to the vault with Raven.

Answer (score 2):

You can watch this episode here http://roosterteeth.com/episode/rwby-volume-5-13zxsre98?page=3
And see Cinder attacks Raven after she killed Raven's friend in a attempt to steal the maiden power. Raven killed Cinder because she killed was pure evil and had to be dealt with. Qrow probably had nothing to do with any of that. Though it's yet to be explained as to why Raven told Cinder to kill Qrow in a earlier episode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about if it was a trick or not but Cinder tried to kill Raven to steal the maiden power so in defense Raven kills Cinder which may or may not have been planned already.

Comment: Can you be specific about when this happened?

Answer (score 1):

Raven was trying to play a long game in order to get her hands on the artifact. She needed Cinder's crew to get to the vault (since they had the subverted Lionheart and his knowledge of how to get to it), so she had to convince them she was on their side. The surest way of showing that was to tell them to go after Qrow. On the other hand however, she also provided hints to Qrow and the good guys that something was up so they wouldn't be caught totally unprepared because she needed as many people as possible, on both sides, tied up in fighting. Attacking Qrow herself was to further prove her loyalty to Cinder. Not that Cinder necessarily bought it, but it was enough to convince Team Salem that she wasn't secretly working with Oz and company, which was enough to get her access to the vault.

It was obviously Raven's intention that Cinder was never going to come out of the vault. Of course, in Cinder's mind, Raven wasn't either. It just so happened that Cinder struck first (at the wrong target).

As for Qrow, Raven convinced herself she didn't care one way or the other whether he lived or died as he'd previously rejected her urging to abandon Oz. He'd turned his back on her and their tribe, so she was using him for her own purposes. His survival, or death, was unimportant.